# How to use IP restrictions when using Google Direction API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-directions-api

I read in the docs that in order to use Google Direction API Web Service, [I needed to use IP restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#restriction). So to achieve this feature, I've created a proxy server that serve me the direction I want. The link looks like so:

```
https://myapp-44th7.uc.r.appspot.com/?origin=22.174181,33.6436763&destination=22.189821,33.640532
```

When I use an **unrestricted** API key and I access this URL in a browser, it works fine, I get the desired JSON file. The problem comes when I want to restrict it. I cannot add a single IP address as a restriction because my Android app is used by users with many different IP addresses. I have hard times trying understanding how to restrict this. Please help solve this issue. What IP should I add?

---

**Edit:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
)

const directionAPIKey = "..............uFvjU"
const directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%s&destination=%s&mode=%s&key=%s"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    appengine.Main()
}
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    direction, err := fetchDirection(ctx, r.FormValue("origin"), r.FormValue("destination"), r.FormValue("mode"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Write(direction)
}

func fetchDirection(ctx context.Context, origin string, destination string, mode string) ([]byte, error) {
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Get(fmt.Sprintf(directionURL, origin, destination, mode, directionAPIKey))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
}
```

The `directionAPIKey` being the key that I use in my URL to access:

```
https://myapp-44th7.uc.r.appspot.com/?origin=22.174181,33.6436763&destination=22.189821,33.64053&key=..............uFvjU
```

[And the one for which I added the restriction in the GCP](https://i.ibb.co/jgm66Sb/Capture.jpg). `172.217.23.52` being the IP that comes when I ping `myapp-44th7.uc.r.appspot.com`.

Comment: The IP address of your server (not of the individual devices calling it).  Requires your server to have a fixed IP address.  You protect your key by only using it on the code on your server, which you control (and don't publish publicly)

Comment: @geocodezip If I ping `myapp-44th7.uc.r.appspot.com`, yes, I get a fixed IP address. If I add that IP as a restriction in GCP, I get the following error message when trying to access it. `This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 35.243.XX.XX, with empty referer`. I'm not sure I understand what you mean through " You protect your key by only using it on the code on your server"?

Comment: Append the key to the request sent from your server (which needs to have a fixed IP address) to Google's servers.

Comment: @geocodezip So you basically say that the restricted key should be appended to the URL in my question? Does the order matter, if the key is added first or as last in the URL?

Comment: See the documentation on how to create a web service request.

Comment: @geocodezip I tried adding the key as mentioned but I got the same behavior. I read everything in docs but I didn't find anything related to this. Can you please help me with my problem?

Comment: What does the code look like in your proxy server?  That is where the key should be added to the request.

Comment: @geocodezip Please check my updated question. Thanks again for taking the time to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For you to restrict your API keys with IP restrictions, you need to add your server's **public facing IP address** as a restriction to your API key. More information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_HZObVbe-g&feature=youtu.be&t=180).

Once you have applied IP restrictions to your API key, **only requests from your specific server(in your case your proxy server) is allowed** to use your **restricted API key**. This means that all requests which come from **different IP addresses** other than the one you have set as restriction are blocked. This is the reason why you are getting an error if you tried to send a request directly from your browser using your restricted API key since your browser has a different IP address than your proxy server.

To make sure that your restricted API key works, you can verify if you can successfully send a [Directions API request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests) through your proxy server using your restricted API key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't solve my issue. However, I have added a new more detailed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597736/unable-to-get-direction-when-using-a-proxy-server-with-an-app-that-is-added-in-g). Please take a look. Voted-up.

Comment: Any idea on the second [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597736/unable-to-get-direction-when-using-a-proxy-server-with-an-app-that-is-added-in-g)? Thanks in advance.